# CSS - Select row table without first column

Tags: css

I want select row in css without first column. I tried like this, but not working:

```
#testTable tbody tr:not(td:first-child):hover{ /*Code*/ }
```

Does anyone know the answer to this problem?

Comment: do you mean you want to select all the rows excluding the first column?

Comment: Specifically: select all cells in one row excluding the first column. I used hover on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#testTable tbody tr:hover td:not(:first-child) { 
  /* ... */
}
```

or — if you need to support older browser, like `IE8` and `IE7` — you may write

```
#testTable tbody tr:hover td + td {
  /* ... */
}
```

this will select all columns inside `tbody` except the first one of each row (when you hover the row)

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aItBr/

Comment: One problem. I use hover on this select and I want select in row all cells without first. (Change background on hover)

Comment: you should specify this also on your question, anyway use `tr:hover` (see my update)